# RuntimeException throwed after receiving a notification

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented push notifications on my C# Xamarin.Android project like they do it in the official firebase documentation.

It is possible to send notifications with the firebase console. Now I tried to send messages from another C# service. The device monitor says, that the GCM message was delivered.

See Android device monitor messages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hm1H.jpg

Here's my code. Why could this happen?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:label="myApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
  </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
</application>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService()
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Service called");
    }
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        string msg = message.GetNotification().Body;
        Log.Debug(TAG, msg);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it work with this manifest configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.xxxxx.xxxx" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:versionCode="2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="XX xXx">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I got an AndroidRuntime error at MyApp.Droid.MyFirebaseMessagingService.OnMessageReceived with this config

Comment: can you post your log?

Comment: It works now. But if the app is open, theres no notification. If the app is closed, it works.